# navbar with fixed position and content with relative position

Tags: html, css

This is a simple question, but I'm not quite sure about the answer.

Can we put a div on hidden but the content stay visible?

because im working on something with this

```
#navigation{
   position:fixed;
   height: 50px;
}
div#slider{
    background:#ccc;
    height:400px;
    position:static;}
.invi{
    background:#000;
    position:relative;
    visibility:hidden;
    height:50px;}
.insideinvi{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    }
```

```js
$(".skippage").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
    }, 300);
});
// Hide Header on on scroll down

(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        breakpoint: 768,
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
        if (settings.format != 'select') {
          cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
          $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
              mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
            }
            else {
              mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
              if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                mainmenu.find('ul').show();
              }
            }
          });

          multiTg = function() {
            cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
              if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
              }
              else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
              }
            });
          };

          if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
          else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
        }

        else if (settings.format === 'select')
        {
          cssmenu.append('<select style="width: 100%"/>').addClass('select-list');
          var selectList = cssmenu.find('select');
          selectList.append('<option>' + settings.title + '</option>', {
                                                         "selected": "selected",
                                                         "value": ""});
          cssmenu.find('a').each(function() {
            var element = $(this), indentation = "";
            for (i = 1; i < element.parents('ul').length; i++)
            {
              indentation += '-';
            }
            selectList.append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + indentation + element.text() + '</option');
          });
          selectList.on('change', function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
          });
        }

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($(window).width() > settings.breakpoint) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
            cssmenu.removeClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').hide();
            }
            else {
              cssmenu.find("#menu-button").removeClass("menu-opened");
            }
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= settings.breakpoint && !cssmenu.hasClass("small-screen")) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            cssmenu.addClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').show();
            }
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    format: "dropdown"
  });

  $("#cssmenu a").each(function() {
   var linkTitle = $(this).text();
   $(this).attr('data-title', linkTitle);
  });
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
html,body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;}
 
.IndexSection{
 font-size:2em;
 color:#ccc;
 width:100%;
}
 
div#welcome {
 height: 100vh;
 background: white;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0;
 position:relative;
}
.welcometext{
 background-color:red;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 height:70%;
 width:80%;
 float:none;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
}
.skippage{
font-size:12px;
color:red;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:2%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-2%);
}
header.navigation{
 position:fixed;
 background:#9C0;
 font-size:12px;
 height:50px;
 left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0; 
 } 
div#content {
 padding-top:50px;
 height: 2000px;
 background: yellow;
}

div#slider{
 background:#ccc;
 height:400px;
 position:static;}
.invi{
 background:#000;
 position:relative;
 visibility:hidden;
 height:50px;}
.insideinvi{
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 height:10px;
 }


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {

  text-align:center;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3db2e1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: red;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: #dff2fa;
  background: #19799f;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: red;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a::before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  border-top: 2px solid #dff2fa;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dff2fa;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  background: #dff2fa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Home</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/navigation.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">

  </head>
<body>
            <header class="navigation nav-down">
<div id='cssmenu' class="row">
<ul class="form-group">
   <li class='active col-lg-2 col-sm-12'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12"><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12"><a href='#'>3</a></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12"><a href='#'>4</a></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12"><a href='#'>5</a></li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12"><a href='#'>6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
            </header>

<div id="welcome" class="IndexSection row">
            <div class=" welcometext">
            welcome
            </div>
    <a href="#" class="skippage">Go Down</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="slider" class="col-xs-12">
   
<div class="invi">
 <div class="insideinvi">2</div>
 <div class="insideinvi">3</div>
</div>
      slider
    </div>
Content
</div>
</body>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="style/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- custom -->
    <script src="style/main.js"></script>
     <script src="style/navigation.js"></script>
     
</html>
```

a fixed navigation and a content which is need to be a relative position because nested div would be an absolute position to set the things in place. is that possible? or maybe some other clue?

change the `#invi` into relative and set the position of `.insideinvi` into a place without troubling the navigation. is that possible?

Comment: Could you provide HTML?

Comment: granted.. thx for ur respond @JeffArries

Comment: Thanks for the HTML.  `div`'s don't show in the first place, only the content shows.  I'm confused about what you're asking, could you revise your question?

Comment: @JeffArries thing is, i have fixed navbar. And i want to make a slideshow in the content div. In order to set the anchor and next/prev button i need div.invi to be relative and div.insideinvi to be absolute. But it will mess with navigation.. any solution to do that? My thought is set the div.invi to be relative and hidden and div.insideinvi to be absolute and visible.. but it won't work, because the css character doesn't work that way. :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with parents `visibility:hidden` and child `visibility:visible`

parents `visibility:hidden` and child `display:block` is not clear solution and i should not work.

(Maybe) better solution would be to make a div without background - so you don't have to make him hidden

Comment: but the .insideinvi div still troubling the navigation.. thx for ur respond. any other solution?